# Scala PriorityQueue conflict resolution?

Tags: scala, priority-queue

I'm working on a project that uses a PriorityQueue and A*. After digging around a ton I think part of the problem that I'm encountering while my search tries to solve my problem is in the PriorityQueue. I'm guessing that when it generates nodes of equal scoring (for example one earlier, and one later) it will chose the one from earlier rather than the one that was most recently generated.

Does anyone know if a PriorityQueue prioritizes the newest node if the scores are the same? If not, how can I make it do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try testing this?  What happens if you create a `PriorityQueue` and insert several items with the same weight?  Should be trivial to confirm.

Comment: @dimo414: It might generate a counterexample, but doesn't actually confirm anything. It might be coincidence.

Comment: If it generates a counterexample, it answers your question (does a PriorityQueue prioritize the newest node?  No.)  Even if you're looking for the conceptual answer, taking the time to explore the practical answer is worthwhile, for yourself and others who might come across your post, as well as people who might try to answer your question.  The more effort you show you've put into a question, the more others will be willing to help you.

Comment: In this case, simply looking at the [`PriorityQueue` documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue) would have told you it is backed by a heap, which you could have easily verified is "[not a sorted structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)".

Comment: You may be interested in my project [scala-prioritymap](https://github.com/ummels/scala-prioritymap), which gives you an immutable priority queue variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PriorityQueue` uses a heap to select the next element.  Beyond that it makes no guarantees about how the elements are ordered.  If it is important to you that nodes are ordered by addition order, you should keep a count of the number of items added and prioritize by the tuple `(priority, -order)`.

If you do anything else, even if it happens to work now, it may break at any arbitrary time since the API makes no guarantees about how it chooses from among equal elements.